# Password never working

Tags: applescript

No matter what my password is, it always says my password isn't right! Help please. Here is the script

```
set my_password to display dialog ¬

"Please enter your password:" with title ¬

"Password" with icon stop ¬

default answer ¬

"" buttons {"Cancel", "OK"} default button 2 ¬

with hidden answer

if (text returned of my_password) is no then

display dialog "Running the application!" buttons ["OK"] default button 1

else if (text returned of my_password) is not no then

display dialog "Did not enter correct password!" buttons ["OK"] default button 1

end if
```

Comment: did you forget your password?

Comment: No, cause it says "If (text returned of my_password) is no then... so no is the password.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must put the password (no) in quotes.

I also shortened the script. Try it out:

```
display dialog "Please enter your password:" with title "Password" with icon stop default answer "" buttons {"Cancel", "OK"} default button 2 with hidden answer

if (text returned of result) is "no" then

    display dialog "Running the application!" buttons ["OK"] default button 1

else

    display dialog "Did not enter correct password!" buttons ["OK"] default button 1

end if
```